# CodeIgniter 500 Internal Server Error 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is actually my first time to upload a CodeIgniter project to a web server. I am having trouble in going to other pages but the index() of the default controller works.

I have searched same situations in the internet but I cannot find any solution.

Here is the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /schoolportal
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

When I try to remove the RewriteBase or change it to just "/", I get a 404 Not Found error.

Here is the config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sctportal.org/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And the route file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'SchoolPortal';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: First you need to make sure rewrite mod is enabled?

Comment: How to know if its enabled?

Comment: Use phpinfo(); function and search rewrite

Comment: I can't see anything about mod rewrite there. What is the exact option name?

Comment: Try with changing this line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`. Notice additional question mark.

Comment: See "mod_rewrite" into "Loaded Modules"

Comment: Can you please show us the base url in the config file

Comment: There is no mod_rewrite in my phpinfo();

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://sctportal.org';

Comment: Have you tried with the updated ans @aronccs

Comment: Yes, still not working

Comment: Juts note lower case for routes best `$route['default_controller'] = 'schoolportal';` and this is good http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: I have found the problem. The URL is case-sensitive. When I try `http://www.sctportal.org/schoolportal/login`, it won't work. But when I try `http://www.sctportal.org/SchoolPortal/login`, it works. How can I make all of them to be insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Do some tweaking in config.php:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

One more thing if you use Linux Server so make these changes is compulsory.

1) Your class name should start with Capital Letter i.e `cat` should be `Cat`.

2) Save the controller class with Capital Letter i.e `cat.php` should be `Cat.php`.

Comment: also mention the versions

Comment: You upload it to main directory or subdirectory and one more thing is this server is Linux ?

Comment: The htaccess file is in the main directory

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update you .htaccess to the below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] d
```

And you please check you base_url in config file as

```
$root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Remove the index.php from the

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

if you don't want the index.php in your url

Comment: can you please update your with the config file along with the route file. So we have a look.

Comment: If you replace the htaccess with my given code and also updated base_url with my given code it should work. So can we have the url which where it show the error as you mention that the index() works perfect

Comment: It still gives me 404 page not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122905/discussion-between-vivek-shah-and-aronccs).